# Why does Angular trigger ChangeDetection on parent components on DOM events despite OnPush strategy?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Trick question I haven't found any answer in the documentation yet.

A change detection cycle is triggered when `AppRef.tick()` is beeing called (mostely by the NgZone patches). It goes from the root component at the top of the tree to the bottom passing by :

- every components with Default strategy
- every components marked by `markForCheck` (and their ancestors)

And skipping non-marked OnPush components.

But why, when a event is fired by a component, all its ancestors will also be checked ? As if `markForCheck` were called.

I was expecting the same behavior as when `AppRef.tick` is called. It doesn't make sense to me why OnPush parents are being checked. That behavior can well be seen on [this demo](https://danielwiehl.github.io/edu-angular-change-detection/).

Please also see a [working illustration on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onpush-cd-parent?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: `OnPush` does not provide total isolation. Use `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()` for that. Change detection always starts at the root of the application, `OnPush` just makes detection skip that section of the component tree provided those conditions are not met. More info: https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/

Comment: Even detaching the component from the tree, I don't think that stops DOM events from triggering change detection.

Comment: Then why wouldn't the siblings be affected by the CD ?

Comment: When you trigger change detection on the child, it has to go through the parent template to get there, so you can't skip it. You can skip siblings because they're on another branch. Keep in mind these are single page applications, ie. one big index.html file, change detection needs to iterate through the elements of the template.

Comment: In other words, when you trigger change detection on a component, it will travel a path from the root to that component, checking everything on the way. If there are branches that have the default detection strategy it will check those too. The change detector will always check a component it visits, you just control where it travels.

Comment: That's not it. `DetectChanges` doesn't trigger CD in the parents. There must be something particular about DOM events.

Comment: Yeah that article I linked suggests DOM events in any component trigger change detection in the root, so the button click in your example. `detectChanges()` is different in that it starts at that component. It's more like `ApplicationRef.tick()`. Then like I said it works it's way down the tree.

Comment: Even `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()` doesn't seem to stop Zone.js from triggering CD on the root on a button click. It's because it's overridden the events API. You can customize Zone.js or just disable it entirely: https://angular.io/guide/zone

Comment: I think you are missing part that RxJS, including timer in your sample, is zone-patched as well, so every time it will affect change detection as well

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli thanks for your feedback, I removed that part of the code as it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to dive deep into the code of Angular to understand what was happening.

Angular wraps [every event listener using `wrapListener()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/06ca0dcf27a00ca1fcf05be8d67a26c9e532f49e/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/listener.ts#L244). This method is responsible for calling `markViewDirty` when an event is fired.

This particular method `markViewDirty`, is [also the one called by `markForCheck`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a98fa489fb498273bdfde2fa4598893d1d53582e/packages/core/src/render3/view_ref.ts#L132).

So this means, every event within the inner-zone is expected to trigger CD on parent components (marked as dirty + `tick()` triggered).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have the same misunderstanding about OnPush that I had when I started learning about change detection :). The point is: **the OnPush strategy does not change anything about which events trigger a CD cycle**. This is solely [taken care of by zone.js by patching browser APIs](https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/#zonejs). (Unless CD is triggered manually.) zone.js does not care about components and ChangeDetectionStrategies. And CD always starts at the root as [@Chris Hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12914833/chris-hamilton) explained.

The difference in ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default and OnPush is only if the component will actually be CHECKED during a CD cycle.

So the sentence in your original post should rather be:
"OnPush strategy is known to only *mark a component to be checked* in the following cases".

See below an example that I observed with the profiler of the [Angular DevTools](https://angular.io/guide/devtools#profiler). I put a `setTimeout(() => {}, 6000)` in the ngOnInit of the OnPush component, it triggered a CD cycle (the source is "setTimeout"), but it did not cause the component itself to be checked.

[image]

About the differences between manually triggered detectChanges(), tick() and markForCheck():

- `ChangeDetectorReference.detectChanges()` triggers CD on this component and its children by respecting the CD strategy of the children
- `ApplicationRef.tick()` triggers CD for the whole application by respecting CD strategies
- `ChangeDetectorReference.markForCheck()` does NOT trigger CD, but marks all OnPush parents to be checked once in the current or next CD cycle

(well explained [here](https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/#trigger-change-detection-manually))

===
EDIT: answer to the updated question ===

If a browser event listener is triggered in an OnPush component, this leads to the OnPush component being marked for check. Also, it triggers a change detection, that starts at the root of the component.

Your question, if I understand you correctly: Why do all parents of the OnPush component have to be marked for check as well?

Answer: If an OnPush component is not marked for check, not only this component will be skipped, but the whole subtree below this component will be skipped. This means, if the component where the event handler was triggered had a parent with OnPush that would not be checked, it itself would also not be checked. Or, put the other way around, if an component shall be checked, all of it ancestor also have to be checked.

Comment: I updated my question to match reality of CD. But you don't answer the original question : Why parents are being checked on dom events

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, please check if my extended answer answers it.

Comment: Correct my if i'm wrong but `markForCheck` is called by the  `async` pipe not just a OnPush component. So that would have nothing to do with it