# Angular. Why calling MatDrawer.close() works if called on the same level but doesn't if called from the component parent

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qyejur-s13c9g?file=src%2Fparent%2Fparent.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.ts,src%2Fparent%2Fparent.html)

Having OnPush components with next nesting structure: `A` renders `B`, `B` renders `MatDrawer`, it works as expected when `B` calls `this.drawer.close()`. The drawer will be closed. However if we call it from the `B`'s parent component `A` via `@ViewChild` it is not going to work unless we additionally specify `this.cdr.markForCheck()` in `B`. (In both cases we have a button with (click) in `A` and `B`). I know that `markForCheck` makes current component to be checked in CD and let's child components `ngDoCheck` to also be called. But I didn't find anything helpful inside of `ngDoCkeck` functions of MatDrawer

The question: why it works when it's called from `B`. And how can I achieve the same behavior in my components without calling `markForCheck()` or empty `@Output`;

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation for `OnPush` from the documentation!

**Using OnPush**

> OnPush change detection instructs Angular to run change detection for a component subtree only when:
>
> - The root component of the subtree receives new inputs as the result of a template binding. Angular compares the current and past value of the input with ==
> - Angular handles an event (for example using event binding, output binding, or @HostListener ) in the subtree's root component or any of its children whether they are using OnPush change detection or not.

If you access via view child, the `@input` values do not change, so there is no need to change detection! you can just create a dummy `@Input` which when you toggle will trigger change detection

This is done internally in angular and not a part of the components `ngDoCheck` to my understanding!

parent ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { SidenavAutosizeExample } from 'src/example/sidenav-autosize-example';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SidenavAutosizeExample, MatButtonModule],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class Parent {
  dummy = false;
  showFiller = false;

  @ViewChild(SidenavAutosizeExample) private child?: SidenavAutosizeExample;

  public toggle(): void {
    this.child?.toggle();
    this.triggerChangeDetection(); // this triggers change detection by just toggling an @Input variable!
  }

  triggerChangeDetection() {
    this.dummy = !this.dummy;
  }
}
```

parent html

```
<sidenav-autosize-example [dummy]="dummy"></sidenav-autosize-example>
<button mat-button (click)="toggle()">
  Parent Toggle button (will not work)
</button>
```

child ts

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  inject,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDrawer, MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

/**
 * @title Autosize sidenav
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-autosize-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-autosize-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-autosize-example.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatSidenavModule, MatButtonModule],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SidenavAutosizeExample {
  @Input() dummy: boolean;
  showFiller = false;
  private cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

  @ViewChild(MatDrawer) private drawer?: MatDrawer;

  public toggle(): void {
    this.drawer?.toggle();
    // this.cdr.markForCheck(); //only works if you do this
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qyejur-vxd1bg)

Comment: Hi there. Yes, indeed, there are hacks to achieve similar behavior instead of calling cdr. But the main question remains, what's so special in matDrawer which makes it open/close only when it's direct parent is markedForCheck? There are neither inputs nor outputs passed.

Comment: @simplygood maybe this will help [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945490/why-does-angular-trigger-changedetection-on-parent-components-on-dom-events-desp) Matthieu Riegler answer!

Comment: unfortunately not :( this question is about why markForCheck works as it works. I did an inspection of a source code of a drawer and notice that animation observable is being pushed to toggle the Drawer. But it is still a big question for my why it is only triggered when a direct parent is markedForCheck. I am filling strange because why material team simply didn't put markForCheck into their toggle() method. This would simplify the world a lot, but now I can’t calm down until I understand their magic